# Is there a log analytics query to get the ADF pipleine details that are running more than 24 hours?

Tags: azure-data-factory, kql, azure-log-analytics

I tried the below query to get the pipelines that are in progress for more than 1 day.
however it retrieved the results of the pipelines that were once in progress from the past 24 hours.

```
ADFActivityRun
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where Status contains "progress"
| extend dataFactory=split(ResourceId, '/')[-1]
| project TimeGenerated, dataFactory, OperationName,Status, PipelineName
| summarize count() by PipelineName, tostring(dataFactory), Status,TimeGenerated
```

My requirement is to get only those pipeline results that are running more than 24 hours.
Could anyone please let me know if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The below query may work for you.

```
ADFPipelineRun
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d)
| where Status == 'InProgress'
| where RunId !in (( ADFPipelineRun | where Status in ("Succeeded","Failed","Cancelled") | project RunId ))
| where datetime_diff('hour',now(),Start) > 24
| extend dataFactory=split(ResourceId, '/')[-1]
| project TimeGenerated, dataFactory, OperationName,Status, PipelineName
| summarize count() by PipelineName, tostring(dataFactory), Status,TimeGenerated
```

It will give the pipelines which are `InProgress` and not completed even after 24 hours.

Please check this output for your reference:

[image]

As I don’t have any pipelines which are running more than 24 hours, It is not displaying any details.

Please check the below result where my pipelines are InProgress for some time and failed but the execution time is more than 1 second here.
[image]

You can try the above query to get pipeline details which are running more than 24 hours and still running.

**Reference:**

https://www.techtalkcorner.com/long-running-azure-data-factory-pipelines/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `summarize arg_max(...) by ...` to find the latest state of every ADF pipeline details. See more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction).